# SyntaxError:Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, syntax-error, unexpected-token

[Error it self](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIyy3.png)

[How it looks in VScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1WCx.png)

Thats Toollsit component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import Toolitem from './Toolitem'
 import App from '../App';
  const styles = {
  ul:{
    listStyle:"none", 
     width:"300px"
    }
  }


  export default  function Toollsit(toto,title){
  return(
   {toto.map((toto)=>{return (<Toolitem toto={toto} />)})} 
  );
 };
```

Thats Toolitem component
import React from 'react';

```
      const Toolitem = ({toto}) => {
         return (
             <div>
                <li>
                 {toto.title}
                </li>
              </div>
              );
            };

            export default Toolitem;
```

And thats my App.js

```
       import react from 'react';
       import Toollsit from './components/Toollsit'
         function App(props) {
           const toto =[
            {id:1,title:'First',completed:true},
            {id:2,title:'Second',completed:false},
            {id:3,title:'Third',completed:true},
         ];
             return (
                <span className="wrapper">
                 <Toollsit toto={toto} />
                </span>
               );
              }

          export default App;
```

Thank you for any help,critic  I truly appreciate your feedback

Comment: If `Toollsit` is a functional component, you probably meant to pass both `toto` and `title` as a single props object, eg `function Toollsit({ toto, title })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must place the `map` function in `<React.Fragment>` tag (equivalent: `<>`). Additionally, the arguments should be destructed object.

```
  export default  function Toollsit({toto, title}){
  return(<>
   {toto.map((toto)=>{return (<Toolitem toto={toto} />)})} 
  </>);
 };
```